# Nosql Database suggestion for high performance

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, redis, database, nosql

We have requirements that force us to have two layers of databases. A good caching solution backed by large distributed database. We are thinking to use redis for fast read and write. We are not yet settled for the database at backend, however we would prefer it to have following properties:

1. consistent over time.
2. robust (no data loss).
3. reasonably fast read.
4. distributed.

We are exploring cassandra and Mongodb as our options. Hbase might be a option too. Kindly let us know your views/ current state of work. We are expecting some comparative analysis which could be like in http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis , but should be more upto date and can give us better insight.  An example usecase could be like when someone post a comment in facebook. The comment is then visible to all its friends in real time.

Comment: Your question does not match the charter of this site.  One red flag is when you say "Kindly let us know your views."  This isn't a survey site.

Comment: what's the actual problem to solve?

Comment: @tolitius we gave the usecase in question. We need to do similar operations that is bottleneck for us.

Comment: @JohnZwinck it was a polite gesture. Moreover, such questions have been answered on this website. Our reason for asking here again is because technologies have changed over the time. We have in particular asked for some insightful analysis as to why should we use a particular database given our need. The existing questions which are asked over 1-2 years ago with some good answers shows that people earlier believed that the question was indeed constructive.

Comment: strangely all the people who voted to close this question though have high points but does not have nosql in their preferred tag list.